# Is there a geodetic benchmark that is fixed with respect to plate tectonics?

Tags: gps, geodesy

I see that NGS benchmarks are used to monitor the movement of geologic plates.

Is one of the benchmarks assumed to be in a fixed location, with movements of all other benchmarks measured with respect to it, or are all benchmarks moving as a result of plate tectonics?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The [IERS reference meridian](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prime_Meridian#IERS_Reference_Meridian) is a weighted average of ground-based monitoring stations.  Thus, tectonic monitoring must involve the motion of one's own plate relative to this global average motion.

Comment: @Kirk Thank you for responding with such alacrity!  However, in order to encourage contributions, it might be a good idea in general to hold off for a few days before accepting responses.  I for one would love to have someone come along with an amplification or critical remarks or even a totally different answer, especially anyone with direct experience in tectonic monitoring.

Comment: Ok, sounds good.  Also realized this only answers the longitude aspect.  I presume this meridian begins/ends at the poles of rotation. Can we assume that the poles of rotation are always at +/- 90 degrees with respect to GPS?

Comment: @Kirk These systems are geocentric.  After establishing a meridian, the only thing left is to determine the earth's orientation (which precesses slowly, which means time is an essential parameter in any high-accuracy reference system).  The orientation of the earth's axis is defined with reference to a celestial reference system.  Some information is available at http://itrf.ensg.ign.fr/itrs_itrf.php .

Comment: interesting, I wonder if this celestial reference system is what this guy needs http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/2459/what-coordinate-system-should-be-used-to-store-geography-data-for-celestial-coord I get a strange error for the php link you posted, is it a public site?

Comment: @Kirk I'm getting that error now too.  It was a public site yesterday!  Just back up to http://itrf.ensg.ign.fr/ and follow a sequence of links labeled "ITRS and ITRF".