# Spatial database containing coordinates for stars in the sky?

Tags: postgis, postgresql

My goal is to map the Skydome ( stars in the sky projected in earth surface ) using GIS. Has anyone done this before?  I can't find any project close to this.

What I just need to know is if there is a dataset -not the paper or software, just the points (geometry) - of the relative position of the stars in the sky. I mean if I look at the sky I can see a kind of surface where the stars are. This is the Skydome. If this surface is over my table, I have a kind of "MAP" of the sky of my hemisphere. If I have both hemispheres I have the Sky Map of the stars.

[image]

Comment: see this: http://ovidiu-v.tripod.com/maps80/maps80.html

Comment: Related: [What coordinate system should be used to store geography data for celestial coordinates?](http://gis.stackexchange.com/q/2459/753)

Comment: Can you be more specific about what you want to do? The question seems to be a bit nebulous at the moment. :)

Comment: @blah238 : See the picture. To draw stars using celestial coordinates. Burton449 : It's just a map, not a GIS project, but this is what I want to do in GIS.

Comment: Related link is exactly what I want. Paul Ramsey points to a good solution : pgSphere.

Comment: Why have you chosen the tag `web-mapping`?

Comment: There is no correct tags to describe what I looking for ( sky-mapping ? ). I think still web (will be a web application), and still mapping (from sky).

Comment: @blah238, +1 on your comment for using the word "nebulous" on an astronomy-related post.

Comment: I can't see what is "nebulous" in mapping stars projections on earth surface. When you look into sky you can see internal part of a "sphere" and you (earth) is inside. So, if we can draw points on earth surface, we can draw points in sky "surface" too.

Comment: There just isn't much information in your question. Specifics like what software you want to use, who the target audience is, where the data is coming from, etc. are useful to put in a question like this. The reason I asked why you chose that tag is that desktop and web mapping are very different, use different kinds of software, skills and platforms, and your question didn't leave much to go on. Don't leave things up to assumption, be specific and help us help you :)

Comment: SOFTWARE: doesn't matter, I need points in a Spatial Database. TARGET AUDIENCE: Anyone who needs to know star names and position in the sky. What is so difficult to understand? If I ask you `Have someone a table in Spatial Database (Postgre+PostGIS) with all cities in the world?` you will answer YES and give me a link to it. My question is clear: `Have someone a table in Spatial Database (Postgre+PostGIS) with most important stars in the sky?`

Comment: Prehaps: http://www.astronexus.com/node/34
Try: http://astronomy.stackexchange.com/ instead.
Would be nice with a celestial coordinate system to QGIS.

Comment: @Jakob :The The HYG Database is closer than someone can help. I just need to use The Cartesian coordinates. Put on an answer I will accept.

Comment: Remove from hold, please.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Jakob gives me the right direction here: http://astronexus.com/node/34

And I have more information here : https://astronomy.stackexchange.com/questions/1556/convert-coordinates-between-ra-dec-and-wgs-84-srid-4326